# Reference list and custom Petrel worksteps

Tags: ocean, petrel

Is is possible to use a Reference list as an input in custom Petrel worksteps?  I am using DescribedArgumentsByReflection as the base class for my arguments package.  I have tried setting the reference list argument to an object, IEnumerable, ReferenceValue and it is always null.